# PHP - Is this secure enough for unique session tokens?

Tags: php, database, security, authentication

I am creating a PHP application and need user authentication to be as secure as possible!

Once the user has logged-in I need to set a cookie (along with other cookies) with a session identifier and this has to be unique.

```
<?php

// Set default timezone for time() function.
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

$secure_token_length = 16; // 32-Digits Long.

// Generate unique token.
$token = time() . "-" . bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($secure_token_length, $strong));

// Set session identifier.
setcookie("session", $token, 0, "/app/", false, false, true);

?>
```

As you can see I'm creating a unique token and appending the current UNIX timestamp to ensure that this value is not generated twice, The secure token is stored in a database within a UNIQUE column and the token is not inserted into the database if it is already in use (Using PHP's Do-While function), Any advice on how to make this more secure please comment.

Comment: Appending the time shouldn't be necessary. If it is then your random session ID is nowhere near big enough to be secure.

Comment: One question back to you, why you have to do more typing declaring $secure_token_length = 16 as a local var instead just write (openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16, $strong) ? :D

Comment: @HendraNucleo It's often preferable to use a named variable rather than using a magic integer to make the code more readable.

Comment: @Chris What do you mean, should I make the session identifier longer..?

Comment: @BradTurner I mean if there is a realistic chance of two session IDs colliding when the time they were generated is taken in to account then the session IDs are not long enough to be secure. In this case though, I think 16 bytes should be enough.

Comment: A bigger concern is https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/80

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be "secure as possible" then please use an established method rather than trying to create your own. For example, let a third-party authenticate for you just like StackOverflow allows you to login with Facebook, Yahoo, etc...

Additionally, PHP has [built-in session handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) functions which can work with both cookies and databases, [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) has a guide on how to securely manage your sessions, I don't understand why you're trying to reinvent the wheel here by generating your own session tokens.

Comment: Thanks Martin, The reason behind this is that this is an internal app with 6 users holding sensitive data and all of the users don't have Facebook, Google accounts. It needs to all be built in house and not rely on any third party.